# Can an MVC web app and an API web app run in the same pool?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asynchronous

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC web application (C#) that is a module of a larger application as a whole (mostly desktop/win service based - VB.NET). Currently the application makes HTTP calls to a web service (provided as an API) which is it's own independent application (also using MVC, VB.NET). Possibly not how I would design it, but it is what I have inherited.

My issue is this: If I host the MVC app in local IIS and run the API project in IIS Express, all is good.  If I split the two projects up to run in separate Application Pools in local IIS, all is good. However, if I run both apps out of the same pool in IIS, I run into a lot of issues.  Namely, timeouts when I make the call to **HttpClient.GetAsync(url)** - especially on a page that is calling this 9 times to dynamically retrieve different images based on ID (each call is made to MVC app which then makes the call to the API). Some calls make it through, most do not.

The exceptions relate to cancelled tasks (timeout = 100s) - but the actions require a fraction of a second so there is no need to timeout. Execution never even makes it into the functions in the API side when it fails - like the HTTP client has given up offering any more connections, or the task is waiting for HTTP to send the request and it never does.

I have tried making it Async all the way through, tried making the HttpClient static, etc.  But no joy.  Is this simply something that just shouldn't be done - allowing the two apps to share an app pool? If so, I can live with that. But if there is something I can do to handle it more efficiently, that'd be very useful. Any information/resources on this would be very much appreciated. Ta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recently ran into the same issue, it took quite a bit of debugging to work out that using the same applciation pool was the cause of the problem.

I also found this could work if you increase the number of Maximum Worker Processes in the advanced settings for the the application pool.

I'm not sure why this is, but i'm guessing all of the requests are being dealt with by one process and this is causing a backlog and ultimately there are too many resulting in timeouts. (I'd be happy for someone more knowledgeable in IIS to correct me though)

HTH

Edit: On further reading here [Carmelo Pulvirenti's Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carmelop/2013/03/22/how-many-web-applications-per-application-pool/) it seems as though the garbage collector could be to be blame. The blog states that multiple applications running on the same pool share memory, the side effects are;

> It means that GC runs a lot of time per second in order to provide
> clean memory to your app. What is the side effect? In server mode,
> garbage collector requires to stop all threads activities to clean up
> the memory (this was improved on .NET Fx 4.5, where the collation does
> not require to stop all threads). What is the side effect?
>
> 1. Slow performance of your web application
> 2. High impact on CPU time due to GC’s activity.